# Visual Studio 2013 Floating Point Support fix?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, runtime

I have a DLL, which is commercial software, so therefore I cannot show the code here...

I get the error "6002" -floating point support not loaded, but only on some applications.

This dll is hooked to several applications, without problems.
I tried everything that I found on Google, like reinstalling VC++, clean PC, registry, everything.

So my conclusion is that either there is another dll compiled in another version of Visual Studio (2010) and it`s somehow conflicting with my dll ?!
Or, I have some memory leak, which I cannot find.
I use the following functions in my DLL which (I think) is the issue:

```
sscanf(); // DISABLED IT FOR TEST, BUT STILL GET ERROR
fprintf_s();
DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
DetourRestoreAfterWith();
_beginthreadex();
strtoul();
```

Example function I use for logging:

```
void ##SOFTWARE-CLASS##::write_log(char *text)
{

    FILE *write_log;        
    char dateStr [9];
    char timeStr [9];
    _strdate( dateStr);
    _strtime( timeStr );

    write_log = fopen("##SOFTWARE-FILE##","a+");
    fprintf_s(write_log,"[%s %s] %s \n", dateStr, timeStr, text);
    fclose(write_log);
}
```

Nothing else is used that may cause floating errors...
The dll is hooked properly, I have no warnings, and no errors.
I must mention, that I have created an empty DLL, with a MessageBox, at the first run, I was getting the same error, but after switching to **/fp:strict**, the error disappeared. So I did the same thing to my project, but the error is still there. I even recoded the whole project, just to see if it fixes the problem, but no.
Please give me advice on how can I solve this problem, as this is the third day that I am testing...

Comment: Can you make sure each application has a floating point variable, even if you never use it?

Comment: @MarkRansom, no i cannot... the rest of application and DLL`s are allready made :( my software is just a plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN : R6002](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1x26e0x(v=vs.120).aspx) the document says that a program will only load floating point support if needed.  What this means, is that the detoured code is being injected into binaries which did not initialize the floating point subsystem.  The solution would be to relink your commercial product without requiring the floating point code, or to relink with an alternative floating point library.

You could try and detect the missing initialization and perform it yourself, but that would have a larger impact on the injected system, and possibly create instabilities.

Use a debugger with the failing executable, and you should be able to get a call stack which identifies where the failure occurs.

Comment: The floating point state is a feature of the process, so if you are going to perform floating point operations, and the floating point state has not been initialized, it may impact other things (MMX behavior).